# Why do we want connections on (Riemannian) manifolds to be torsion-free?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I can see why we want a connection on a Riemannian manifold to be compatible with the metric. But why do we want our connections to be torsion-free? Why do we even care about torsion? Is it just to get uniqueness of the Riemannian connection?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/20510/120644 

See here. This answer is what informs my intuition on this.